# Volume mute and unmute using javaScript

Tags: javascript, html, aframe

I want to mute and unmute volume using javaScript.

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('volume', {
 init: function () {
   var buttonVolume = document.querySelector('#control-volume');
   var buttonMute = document.querySelector('#control-mute');
   var vid = document.querySelector('#video-src');
   //vid.setAttribute('volume', this.value);
   this.el.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
   //alert(this.vid.muted);
   if(this.vid.muted === true){
    this.vid.muted = false;
    buttonVolume.setAttribute('visible', 'true');
    buttonMute.setAttribute('visible', 'false');
  }
  else{
    this.vid.muted = true;
    buttonVolume.setAttribute('visible', 'false');
    buttonMute.setAttribute('visible', 'true');
  }
}, false);
 }
 });
```

This is my code. But always `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'muted' of undefined` this is showing. How to solve this error?

```
<video id="video-src" style="display:none"  
           autoplay="true" loop="false" crossorigin="anonymous" playsinline webkit-playsinline>
      <!-- MP4 video source. -->
      <source id="load" type="video/mp4"/>
    </video>
  <a-image volume id="control-volume" class="clickable" width="0.4" 
 height="0.4" src="#volume-normal" position="3 -4.440 -3.542" scale="1.3 1.3 
  1.3"></a-image>
  <a-image volume id="control-mute" class="clickable" width="0.4" height="0.4" src="#volume-mute" position="3 -4.440 -3.542" scale="1.3 1.3 1.3" visible="false">
  </a-image>
```

This one is my html coding. How to solve that error. What's the reason? Why that error is showing?

Comment: Why would `var vid = document.querySelector('#video-src');` show up as `this.vid` in the event handler? -  try `if (vid.muted)` - also where is the video-src in your HTML?

Comment: Video source i got like that. Should I remove this?

Comment: Just remove ‘this.’

Comment: Yes. It's fine.

Comment: Feel free to delete the question

Answer (score 0):

Posting as answer. There was typo in code.

`var vid` was referenced as `this.vid`. Removed the `this`.